# What is the proper way to set up multiple references to one table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres and setting up my schema in an SQL file for an app I am building. I have tables: users, posts, templates and a junction table users_posts_templates.

- Users is 1:N with Posts
- Users is also 1:N with Templates
- users_posts_templates is meant to act as a junction so that a Post owned by a User can have N templates from any and all Users, my schema is set up as such:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL 
        CHECK (position('@' IN email) > 1),
    address TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);

-- CREATE TYPE category AS ENUM ('environment', 'health care', 'defense');
-- CREATE TYPE states AS ENUM ('USA', 'AL', 'AK', 'AS', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FM', 'FL', 'GA', 'GU', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MH', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'MP', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PW', 'PA', 'PR', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VI', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY');
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  link TEXT,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  tag category NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  location states NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE templates (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE users_posts_templates (
  post_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES templates(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (username, post_id, template_id)
)
```

I get the error when I build `ERROR:  relation "users" already exists`

How do I set up my relationships so that the Posts table and junction table can both reference Users or is there a better approach I should consider?

Comment: "I get the error when I build `ERROR:  relation "users" already exists`" -- Drop `users` before you (re)create it or just `ALTER` it.

Comment: @stickybit, the issue with a `DROP users` is you will need to add `CASCADE` and `DROP` all the referencing tables also, which maybe overkill.  `ALTER` is a solution as well as `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ...`.

Comment: Hey thank you both so much, I have a separate file to go through the DROP and CREATE process, but I was locking up the db with a terminal I didn't see..

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PostgreSQL you are using? I tested on the Postgre 13 and Postgre 14 this script, no error, all tables and foreign keys were created.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL 
        CHECK (position('@' IN email) > 1),
    address TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);


CREATE TABLE posts (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  link TEXT,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(30) NOT null
  REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  tag text NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE templates (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  body TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE users_posts_templates (
  post_id INTEGER NOT NULL
  REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL
  REFERENCES templates(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (username, post_id, template_id)
);
```

I do not know your business logic, so maybe I am thinking incorrectly. I think the `username` field in the `users_posts_templates` table is unnecessary. Because if we need it, we can get it from the `posts` table using `users_posts_templates.post_id`
[image]